# Impressão em excel com php e jquery

Tags: php, jquery, microsoft-excel

Estou tentanto imprimir para excel um consulta apresentada em tabela com php e jquery na tag `<tbody>`. No entanto não funcionou. Apresentou no excel um resultado errado com todo o HTML de resultado em uma única célula. PODERIAM ME AJUDAR?

Encontrei a solução no site http://nice-tutorials.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/export-to-excel-in-php-with-jquery.html

### HTML e PHP

```
<form action="frameworks/teste.php" method="post"
    onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>").append( $("#minhaTabela").eq(0).clone() ).html() )'>
    <table id="minhaTabela" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>DM Clarity</th>
            <th>Mantis</th>
            <th>Sistema</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Situação</th>
            <th>Prioridade</th>
            <th>Previsão Homol.</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Export to Excel</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php  
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');  
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls');  
    // Fix for crappy IE bug in download.  
    header("Pragma: ");  
    header("Cache-Control: ");  
    echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

O teu problema é que o output deve ser após o envio dos headers.

Função [PHP header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

```php
<?php

$nomeFicheiro = "bubu.xls";

$html = "<table><tr><td>Celula A1</td><td>Celula B1</td></tr></table>";

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nomeFicheiro");

echo $html;

?>
```

Para gerar um .XLSX deverás enviar o header:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

**Nota:**
Actualmente esta técnica faz com que o Excel gere um aviso ao abrir o ficheiro.

---

<sup>Créditos da solução para esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12541019/352449) no SOEN colocada pelo @NullPoiиteя.</sup>

[Esta resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689463/352449) apresenta uma possível solução para contornar o aviso, mas obriga a uma markup mais extensa.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esse exemplo de excel com jquery e php não funcione, nos próprios comentários do blog já reclamam.

Use essa biblioteca feita pelos próprios programadores do excel.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Já usei ela, é muito boa e bem completa, serve tanto pra exportar quanto pra importar.